# JFreeChart datasets don't works with JPanel

Tags: java, mysql, jpanel, jfreechart

I have the bellow code which call data from MySQL and return in a XYPlot (JFreeChart) on a JPanel. There are different datasets, depending of the row index of my JTable. The problem is when I select a row, the chart seems to be good, but when I select another row, the XYplot appear but when I make a click (drag, second mouse-click, etc.) the chart returns to the first one. Practically every time when I select another plot, and I make something with the mouse (zooming, etc.), it returns to the primary/first xyplot selection.
I tried JPanel.validate(); but still not working, also repaint(); method. Furthermore, with JFrame it is working very good, no problem (yes! right, because opens every time one frame with the specific XYPlot). I suppose that the problem is from JPanel. Any help/advice? Please!

**UPDATE:** The JPanel with the XYPlot, is encapsulated in an JSplitPanel. When I move the divider (enlarge JPanel with the XYPlot), there are two XYPlot, the first one (obtained on the first click, and the second one (if was clicked second time to another row/dataset -> XYPlot). I suppose that the problem is from query -> and repainting over the previous XYPlot.

```
private void PrimaryTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        int row = PrimaryTable.getSelectedRow();
        int realIndex = PrimaryTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
        String Table_click = (PrimaryTable.getModel().getValueAt(realIndex, 0).toString());

        try {

            String query = "select wavenumber,spectrum FROM test where id_test ='" + Table_click + "'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {

                JDBCXYDataset dataset = new JDBCXYDataset(ConnecrDb(), query);

                JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                        "title",
                        "cm",
                        "in",
                        dataset,
                        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                        false, //legend
                        true, //tooltip
                        false); //urls

                XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();

                ChartPanel CP = new ChartPanel(chart);
                PanelWithChart.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                PanelWithChart.add(CP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                PanelWithChart.repaint();
            }
             rs.close();
            pst.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the values of 'PrimaryTable' when this function gets called? How about sending the value of the query to a debug print when it gets called. Make sure its requesting what you think it should be.

Comment: It's checked! All works fine if is in a JFrame. In the case of JPanel, any mouse event (first/second click, wheel rotation) resets the plot to the first calling/selection plot.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115923).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this may be your problem

```java
PanelWithChart.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
PanelWithChart.add(CP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

By calling `JPanel#add()` you are adding a new component each time `PrimaryTableMouseClicked` is called.  If your `ChartPanel` is the only component on `PanelWithChart` try removing the previous chart:

```java
PanelWithChart.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
PanelWithChart.removeAll();
PanelWithChart.add(CP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This will not work if you have other components on the panel, if this is the case then you will need to use `PanelWithChart.remove(Component comp)` but this is harder as you do not have a referance to the previous chart.

Please not that this is probably not the best way the use a chart, have you considered creating the chart once and making the `dataset` a propery?  You could then use this code in `PrimaryTableMouseClicked` to achieve much the effect.

```java
dataset.removeAllSeries();
XYSeries newSeries = new XYSeries("New Data");
dataset.addSeries(newSeries);
```

Comment: Sir, I really thank you! You don't know how did you saved me! Thanks for your time.